# If $\space\lim _{x\to a}f\left(x\right) = L\space$ for every$\space a\in R,$ then $\space f\left(x\right) = L\space$ for every$\space x \in R$.

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $\space f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R.\space$ If $\space\lim _{x\to a}f\left(x\right) = L\space$ for every$\space a\in R,$ then $\space f\left(x\right) = L\space$ for every$\space x \in R$.

prove or disprove.

I believe it's true.
I assumed my contradiction that $\space f\left(x\right) \ne L\space$ , so it's either $\space f\left(x\right) > L\space$ or $\space f\left(x\right) < L\space$

so that means that $|\space f\left(x\right) - L\space| > 0\space$ and i can choose $\epsilon > 0\space$ to be $|\space f\left(x\right) - L\space|\space$ and get a contrediction.

but I don't know if this direction is even possible. I would love to hear your thoughts.

thanks!

Comment: What if $f$ is zero everywhere except at $x=0$ where it is one?

Comment: What is $a$ in this question?

Comment: I edited that question to include $a$

Comment: but if f is zero everywhere except at x=0 where it is one, then $\space\lim _{x\to a}f\left(x\right) = L\space$ for every $\space a\in R,$ except $a = 1\space$ so it can't be

Comment: What does "$a$" represent?

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1,& x = 0 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Then we have $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$ and for $a \neq 0$ we have $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: first, thank you for answering! but by your definition of f isn't $\space \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 1$ ?

Comment: No, when we write $\lim_{x \to a}$ we mean for all $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that is $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ then blah blah blah. The $0<$ part is what is important here.

Comment: To be frank (although I'm usually Joe), I am no stranger to calculus/analysis but often forget the $>0$ part.